# Weekly Design Challenge - One Month in Review

Tags: discussion

[Thursday Weekly Design Challenge](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2732/thursday-weekly-design-challenge)

> On Thursdays at 15 UTC we're going to be hosting a weekly design challenge. Come in to Ink Spot
>
> Why 15 UTC on Thursdays? Cause I had to pick something. I won't change this for at least a few months since consistency will be key. Hopefully this is late enough our friends on the West Coast will be awake while early enough our users in Europe will still be around too.

Some have suggest different days and/or different times. Please provide feedback ONLY about day and time.

Not including Spectators, which there have been:

- Week 1: 5 Entries
- Week 2: 3 Entries
- Week 3: 4 Entries
- Week 4: 8 Entries
- Week 5: 7 Entries

There will have to be an overwhelming consensus to change it.

Comment: Someone should create a world map of the people who have participated so far so we can see what time zones they are in, using that as data for what time to change to, if any

Comment: @ZachSaucier..  When will you have this map finished??

Comment: @Zach That's really easy to do with a list of postcodes and batchgeo.com - just an FYI.

Comment: If you really wanted to get creative you could scrape the [activity graphs](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/58170/johnb) from the participants to determine the best time slot. ...But I think the current time is fine (conveniently, it's on my most active day and hour).

Comment: @JohnB Do those include time on main as well or just in chat? Because some participants don't really use chat and only come during the comp

Comment: @Zach I think it's just chat. Putting some more thought in to it, it's probably a rolling window of activity. So thinking about it, the fact that my most active day is Thursday is likely a result of the result of the Challenge being on Thursday. I wonder what my most active day was a month ago, it might be different

Comment: @JohnB Maybe a timeline of most active times on main would be insightful?

Comment: 2am Pacific.... Wednesday night.... Just 'cuz 'wednesday' is such a weird word.

Answer (score 8):

Honestly, I don't see any reason to change. It's going well and I don't believe changing the day or time is going to make things better. Overwhelming Consensus being the key - it's not going to happen. We change the time and maybe someone else shows up, but maybe another person can't.

I'd love to see a time we can all make but since I doubt that's going to happen I think the current time works fairly well and has been getting better and better turnout. I also think that changing the time or day can lead to confusion has some people only come for the weekly exercise.

I'd also mention that nothing is stopping someone from doing the exercise later. We've had people shown up towards the end of it and just do it on their own already. If you need to come on an hour or even a day late - go for it.

My feeling is the time and day are still good for now.

Comment: I agree, if it's working don't break it. It's not like the chat here is overwhelmed with people needing help and this is getting in the way.

Comment: I feel like it might also be cool to make/use a website for the archived design challenges - this is a wonderful exercise for any designer and I think it'd be cool to let people access it in a lesson sort of way - like skillshare! :)  just a down-the-road suggestion

Answer (score 2):

Rafael made a suggestion that I thought was a good idea: a separate chat room for the challenge.

I think the separation worked especially well for the Design Volleyball and could work well with this. The plus side is it makes it easier for people to pop in and check out how the format works and see the previous entries and read the wonderful excuses about how uninspired/coffee-deprived/not-currently-aligned-with-Jupiter's-moons the participants are.

Comment: I dont like separate room. The reason people hang on inkspot is thet there is trafick there.

Answer (score 0):

I think weekend would be even more better for this challenge. I work as a full time designer. So, It will be difficult for me to engage in weekdays. It might be the case for few other too.

Why don't we test it by conducting the challenge on weekend? We might get few more entries?

What do you say?

Comment: I suspect the turnout would diminish just based on our traffic analytics. We consistently have twice as many visits and page views on weekdays than on weekend-days. I do pop in to the site on weekends to check for flags but I probably wouldn't be able to attend the challenge on weekends.

Comment: oops, If that is the case I'm gonna miss this challenge :(

Comment: Regardless of the agreed upon time, we welcome anyone who can make it to still participate. Just set a 20 minute timer for yourself and pop in to chat to post your result or edit it in to that week's round-up!

Comment: Sounds good! :)

Comment: If the chat activity is anything to judge by, I am the only one who hangs around on the weekends, haha :P Even then I'm gone half of the time